# Prop being mutated: "isOpen"

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I got this error:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly
> since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component
> re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the
> prop's value. Prop being mutated: "isOpen"

Here is my code

**My child component:**

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="isOpen" max-width="500px">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>Remove</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>Are you sure to delete?</v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn color="primary" text @click="$emit('closedialog')">Close</v-btn>
                <!-- <v-btn color="primary" text @click="deleteItem">Delete</v-btn>  -->
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    // name: 'confirmDelete',
    props: {
        isOpen: Boolean
        // selected: Object
    }
};
</script>
```

**Parent Component:**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="app">
            <v-app id="inspire">
                <v-data-table
                    :headers="headers"
                    :items="contracts"
                    sort-by="createdAt"
                    class="elevation-1"
                >
                    <template v-slot:top>
                        <v-toolbar flat color="white">
                            <v-toolbar-title>CONTRACTS</v-toolbar-title>
                            <v-divider class="mx-4" inset vertical></v-divider>
                            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                            <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
                                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                    <v-btn
                                        color="primary"
                                        dark
                                        class="mb-2"
                                        v-bind="attrs"
                                        v-on="on"
                                    >New Contract</v-btn>
                                </template>

                                <v-card>
                                    <v-card-title>
                                        <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
                                    </v-card-title>

                                    <v-card-text>
                                        <v-container>
                                            <v-row>
                                                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                                    <v-text-field
                                                        label="Start Contract"
                                                        name="name"
                                                        prepend-icon="person"
                                                        placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
                                                        type="text"
                                                        required
                                                        v-model="selectedItem.startDate"
                                                        :rules="nameErrors"
                                                        @input="$v.selectedItem.startDate.$touch()"
                                                        @blur="$v.selectedItem.startDate.$touch()"
                                                        @keyup="clearServerErrors('name')"
                                                    />
                                                </v-col>

                                                <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                                                    <v-select
                                                        v-model="selectedItem.duration"
                                                        :items="[1, 2, 3, 6, 12]"
                                                        label="Duration Contract."
                                                        required
                                                    />
                                                </v-col>

                                                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                                    <v-select
                                                        v-model="selectedItem.leave"
                                                        :items="[20, 26]"
                                                        label="Days off"
                                                    />
                                                </v-col>
                                            </v-row>
                                        </v-container>
                                    </v-card-text>

                                    <v-card-actions>
                                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
                                        <v-btn
                                            color="blue darken-1"
                                            text
                                            @click="onSave"
                                            :disabled="!isValid"
                                        >Save</v-btn>
                                    </v-card-actions>
                                </v-card>
                            </v-dialog>
                        </v-toolbar>
                    </template>

                    <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
                        <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                        <v-icon small @click="showDeleteDialog(item)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
                        <v-icon middle @click="goToRouteLeaves(item)">play_arrow</v-icon>
                    </template>
                </v-data-table>

                <CreateOrEditContract :is-open="isDialogDeleteVisible" @closedialog="close()" />

                <!-- <v-dialog v-model="isDialogDeleteVisible" max-width="500px">
                    <v-card>
                        <v-card-title>Remove</v-card-title>
                        <v-card-text>Are you sure to delete?</v-card-text>
                        <v-card-actions>
                            <v-btn color="primary" text @click="isDialogDeleteVisible = false">Close</v-btn>
                            <v-btn color="primary" text @click="deleteItem">Delete</v-btn>
                        </v-card-actions>
                    </v-card>
                </v-dialog>-->
            </v-app>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ContractService from '../services/ContractService';
import UserContractsService from '../services/UserContractsService';
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate';
import { required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
import CreateOrEditContract from './CreateOrEditContract';
var moment = require('moment');

export default {
    name: 'Admin',
    components: {
        CreateOrEditContract
    },
    mixins: [validationMixin],

    validations: {
        selectedItem: {
            startDate: {
                required,
                isStartDate(value) {
                    return this.isStartDate(value);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            selectedItem: {
                startDate: ''
            },
            serverErrors: {
                startDate: ''
            },
            errorMessage: '',
            error: null,
            validationError: false,
            contracts: [],
            dialog: false,

            isDialogDeleteVisible: false,
            headers: [
                { text: 'Start', value: 'startDate' },
                { text: 'Duration', value: 'duration' },
                { text: 'Leave', value: 'leave' },
                { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false }
            ],
            defaultItem: {
                startDate: '',
                duration: '',
                leave: ''
            }
        };
    },

    created() {
        this.selectedItem = { ...this.defaultItem };
    },

    async mounted() {
        try {
            const { userId } = this.$route.params;
            const { data } = await UserContractsService.index(userId);
            this.contracts = data;
        } catch (error) {
            this.errorMessage =
                (error.response && error.response.data ? error.response.data : null) ||
                error.message ||
                error.toString();
        }
    },

    computed: {
        formTitle() {
            return this.selectedItem.id ? 'Edit Contract' : 'New Contract';
        },

        nameErrors() {
            const errors = [];

            if (!this.$v.selectedItem.startDate.$dirty) return errors;
            !this.$v.selectedItem.startDate.required && errors.push('Date is required');
            !this.$v.selectedItem.startDate.isStartDate && errors.push('Enter valid date');

            return errors;
        },

        isValid() {
            return !this.$v.$invalid;
        }
    },

    watch: {
        dialog(val) {
            val || this.close();
        }
    },

    methods: {
        editItem(item) {
            this.selectedItem = { ...item };
            this.dialog = true;
        },

        async deleteItem() {
            const index = this.contracts.findIndex((contract) => contract.id === this.selectedItemlete.id);
            this.contracts.splice(index, 1);
            this.isDialogDeleteVisible = false;

            await ContractService.delete(this.selectedItemlete.id);

            this.selectedItemlete = { ...this.defaultItem };
        },

        showDeleteDialog(item) {
            this.selectedItemlete = item;
            this.isDialogDeleteVisible = true; //!this.isDialogDeleteVisible;
            //  this.$emit("clicked", !this.isDialogDeleteVisible)
        },

        close() {
            this.isDialogDeleteVisible = false;
            this.dialog = false;
            this.selectedItem = { ...this.defaultItem };
        },

        async onSave() {
            if (this.selectedItem.id) {
                const index = this.contracts.findIndex((contract) => contract.id === this.selectedItem.id);

                await ContractService.save(this.selectedItem);

                this.$set(this.contracts, index, this.selectedItem);
            } else {
                this.selectedItem.userId = this.$route.params.userId;

                const { data } = await ContractService.save(this.selectedItem);

                this.contracts.push(data);
            }

            this.close();
        },

        goToRouteLeaves(item) {
            this.$router.push(`/leaves/${item.id}`);
        },

        clearServerErrors(type) {
            this.serverErrors[type] = [];
        },

        isStartDate(value) {
            return moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid();
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
v-btn {
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-model="isOpen"` your child component is trying to change the props isOpen.
Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.

make change like below:
Parent:

```
<CreateOrEditContract :is-open.sync="isDialogDeleteVisible" @closedialog="close()" />
```

Child:

```
computed: {
  open: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.isOpen
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      this.$emit('update:isOpen', newValue)
    }
  }
}
```

```
<v-dialog v-model="open" max-width="500px">
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `props` work from top to bottom pattern. `isOpen` passed by parent to child, now it's like data flowing from top to bottom. If your child tries to mutate that data, how will parents get informed about that change? The parent will never get informed this way that's why it's a warning to not change the value of prop passed in child. You need to find a way to communicate to parents and parents will update that prop, this way data flow will not break.

Here `v-model` is two-way binding which means it will set the value of the property which is `isOpen` prop.

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="isOpen" max-width="500px">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>Remove</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>Are you sure to delete?</v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn color="primary" text @click="$emit('closedialog')">Close</v-btn>
                <!-- <v-btn color="primary" text @click="deleteItem">Delete</v-btn>  -->
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    // name: 'confirmDelete',
    props: {
        isOpen: Boolean
        // selected: Object
    }
};
</script>
```

Hint:  You can emit `event` to inform parent about the change and make parent change the value of `isOpen`. Try computed getter/setter to achieve this